# How is the Iroha poem usually pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

I have read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha) that the Iroha poem has a modern version with updated hiragana and stuff.

However, it seems that most times people recite the poem (as in, every time I've seen/heard someone recite it), they use the old pronunciation.

If it so happens that I am called upon to recite Iroha, should I use the old or new pronunciation?

As a related side question: if I want to refer to the poem by name, should I call it "i ro wa" by the modern pronunciation, or "i ro ha" by the old pronunciation?

Edit: To clarify: old as in "iro ha nihoheto", new as in "iro wa nioedo".

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'old pronunciation' and 'new pronunciation' - I'd interpret 'old' to mean 'following old kanadzukai rules' (thus 'iro wa nioedo') and 'new' to mean 'reading the kana as written' (thus 'iro ha nihoheto'). I'd go farther and say the real 'old' pronunciation would be more like 'iro wa niwoyendo' :P

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't get what is meant by "Iroha poem has a modern version with updated hiragana and stuff". It sounds like totally different thing than the rest of your question.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha) lists an archaic and modern transliteration. The old version doesn't have voiced consonants, and has some obsolete hiragana or pronunciations, which are changed in the "modern" transliteration. 

As an example, the first line of the "archaic/old" version reads "iro ha nihoheto", while the respective "modern/new" version reads "iro wa nioedo".

Answer (score 10):

Actually, what you mentioned are not *old* and *new* pronunciations. Both are **contemporary** ones.

The "irohanihoheto..." is reading its letter names, while "irowa nioedo..." one, as a meaningful poem. The difference is much clearer if you try the same thing in English alphabet, say, "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz." (a perfect pangram from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)), where "iroha..." corresponds to "see-dublyoo-em-..." reading, and "irowa..." is "koom-fyord-...".

Each letter in Japanese syllabary was supposed to have the same reading as the syllable itself when it was created, but due to [a series of phonological changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language#History), the grammatically valid reading no longer matches the alphabetical one. As for lack of voiced consonants, it's said that today's voiced consonants are remnants of [prenasalized sounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenasalized_consonant) in Classical era, which they had no means to transcribe at that time.

---

**P.S.**
The real "archaic" pronunciation around the 11th century would be like:

> Irofa nifofendo tirinuruwo
>   Wanga yo tarenjo tunenaramu
>   Uwino okuyama kefu ko(y)ete
>   Ashaki yume mishi wefimo shenju

There are also some fun videos reading [the Tale of Genji in Classical pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jEWDiPlxXU).

**P.P.S.**
What your "a modern version with updated hiragana" reminded me of was this (incorporating ん):

> とりなくこゑす　ゆめさませ
>   みよあけわたる　ひんかしを
>   そらいろはえて　おきつへに
>   ほふねむれゐぬ　もやのうち

Which won the 1st prize of the "new pangram" contest held by a newspaper in 1903.

Comment: A funny thing about the "new pangram" is that it contains the string いろは.

Comment: Some words are apparently useful to make pangrams. At least the "medalists" of the contest shared a couple of similar portions with each other. See http://blog.goo.ne.jp/hanasakesake/e/65989b298208a72268334288dbab3820